# When using jQuery and Fade is there a way to prevent the surrounding content from "jumping" downwards?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, fade

I'd really love the surrounding content to "scroll" up/down in like when using Scroll - but would also love the appropriate div to "fade" in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set is opacity to 100% transparent, then do a slide in effect to scroll the content down. Finally, fade the element in again.

Something like:-

```
$("mydiv").css("opacity", "0").slideDown("normal", function() {$(this).fadeIn("normal");});
```

Comment: what'd be the best way to make that a toggle?

Comment: opacity at 1 is 100% *visible*. opacity refers to how opaque it is. opacity at 0 is transparent.